# How should I parse query paramters to a sql query

Tags: javascript, express

How should I be parsing request query parameters and translate that into a database query?

Say I have a url of `/projects` that can sometimes be called with query parameters such as, `/projects?sort=status&part=123` or possibly `/projects?priority=1&owner=baz`

In my express app I have route defined as:

```
app.get('/projects', (req,res) => {

    let query = parse_request(req.query) || default_query;

    database.execute(query, result => res.send(result));
});
```

I will be use a custom `parse_request` function to return the database query I want to execute based on the query parameters or a default query if no parameters were passed.

Is this a sane approach or should I be going about this a different way? Seems like the `parse_request` function could be a bit involved depending on how many query string options I would like to handle.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Austin, postgresql 9.5

Comment: There is a [postgres named parameters](https://github.com/bwestergard/node-postgres-named) plugin that might work for you. That way you could just dump your whole request query in and the library would parse it out for you.